# Интонационные запятые

Tags: запятая

Добрый день. Никак не могу найти правила, описывающего употребление интонационных запятых. Быть может, его и вовсе нет. Но интуиция подсказывает, что иногда они допустимы. К примеру, в таком предложении:

На том заводе я проработал десять лет, заместителем бригадира, потом ушел.

Возможна ли здесь первая запятая или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Иногда  в одном и том же предложении можно ставить или не ставить запятую или тире, тогда эти знаки препинания называют интонационными. Это условный термин, он означает, что постановка запятой (тире) меняет интонацию предложения, но при этом не стоит забывать, что грамматика и семантика также меняются.

(1) На том заводе я проработал десять лет заместителем бригадира, потом ушел. Это простое предложение, "заместителем бригадира" входит в основное сообщение.
(2) На том заводе я проработал десять лет, заместителем бригадира, потом ушел. Это предложение с обособленным дополнением в добавочном сообщении. 
(3) На том заводе я проработал десять лет - заместителем бригадира, потом ушел. Обособление с помощью тире.

Сравнить: Посидели – больше для приличия – несколько минут. Отправились домой – с большой неохотой – только к вечеру. В этих предложениях также возможны вариантные знаки препинания.

Answer (score 2):

Упоминания о запятой как об авторском знаке кое-где можно найти, например у Розенталя в Справочнике по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию,  но перечень знаков препинания, которые  могут являться элементами авторской пунктуации, я не нашла. Впрочем, авторская пунктуация и не может быть регламентирована, т. к. этим термином обозначается отступление от действующих норм пунктуации. Насколько допустим тот или иной вариант, в том числе данный, авторского пунктуационного оформления, я, к сожалению, не могу сказать, но, как бы то ни было, выйти из положения можно и не прибегая к помощи авторских запятых: если необходимо обозначить на письме интонационное выделение, Вы можете оформить выделяемый речевой отрезок как вставную конструкцию, заключив его в скобки или обособив посредством тире. В нормативности этого варианта пунктуационного оформления можно не сомневаться.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, это *уточнение*, которое по правилам русского языка выделяется запятыми)