# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Когда соединяются две частицы, выделяется энергия, а частицы исчезают(,) и появляются разнообразные частицы"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, ссп

Нужна ли запятая в предложении:
**Когда соединяются две частицы разных материй, выделяется энергия, а частицы исчезают(,) и появляются разнообразные частицы.**

По идее, "частицы исчезают(,) и появляются разнообразные частицы" находятся по смыслу вместе. Союз "а" имеет к ним одно и то же отношение.
Но, с другой стороны, это разные предложения, здесь нет однородных членов предложения, тогда запятую поставить нужно. Но, если поставить запятую, как тогда выделить связь этих двух предложений?

Comment: _"частицы исчезают(,) и появляются разнообразные частицы"_ === Нет ли здесь ошибки: частицы и исчезают, и появляются... Может, нужно указать, какие именно частицы исчезают?

Comment: Ваше замечание правильное. Здесь не уточнено, но одни частицы исчезают, а другие появляются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Когда соединяются две частицы разных материй, выделяется энергия, а частицы исчезают(,) и появляются...*

Здесь части сложносочинённого предложения имеют общую придаточную часть (*"Когда соединяются две частицы разных материй"*), потому запятая перед ***и*** не нужна.

См. [***"Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник":***](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

> **§ 112…** В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами ***и, да*** (в значении «и»), ***или, либо*** запятая не ставится в
>   следующих случаях:
>
> 1) если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общий второстепенный
>   член или общую придаточную часть:
>
> <...>
>
> *Когда взошло солнце, роса высохла **и** трава позеленела.*

Comment: Очень спорно, что "когда..." это общая часть двух предложений "частицы исчезают" и "появляются разнообразные частицы". Продолжу в тесте своего ответа.

Answer (score 1):

> Когда соединяются две частицы разных материй, выделяется энергия, а
>   частицы исчезают(,) и появляются разнообразные частицы

Здесь прежде всего надо переформулировать фразу. Три раза частицы без уточнения, какие это частицы - сильно путает.

Что касается запятой, то она спорна. Тут сильно от толкования зависит.

> По идее "частицы исчезают(,) и появляются разнообразные частицы"
>   находятся по смыслу вместе. Союз "а" имеет к ним одно и то же
>   отношение. Но, с другой стороны, это разные предложения, здесь нет
>   однородных членов предложения, тогда запятую поставить нужно. Но, если
>   поставить запятую, как тогда выделить связь этих двух предложений?

Ваши рассуждения имеют весьма косвенное отношение к правописанию. 
Вы должны прежде всего разобраться со структурной схемой предложения. 
можно ли толковать "когда..." как общую часть для всех трех простых предложений, или она относится только к первой. Это вопрос авторского понимания, далеко не всегда можно определиться со стороны.

Насколько понимаю физику, тут идет ряд последовательных событий, каждое предыдущее предопределяет последующее. При такой трактовке логичной была бы следующая пунктуация (с необходимой корректировкой фразы).

***Когда соединяются две частицы разных материй, выделяется энергия; частицы исчезают, и появляются новые частицы".***

"Разнообразные" тут совсем не по стилю, а противопоставление излишне. Но если оно есть, то грамматика фразы другая, тут slava1947, похоже, ошибается.

> Здесь части сложносочинённого предложения имеют общую придаточную часть
>   ("Когда соединяются две частицы разных материй"), потому запятая перед
>   и не нужна.

Очень спорно, что "когда..." это общая часть двух предложений (1)"частицы исчезают" и (2)"появляются разнообразные частицы". Тут другая схема.

"Когда..." можно (не обязательно, причем) трактовать как общую часть двух предложений (1)"выделяется энергия" (2)"частицы исчезают и появляются разнообразные частицы". При этом (2) в свою очередь является сложносочиненным состоит состоит из двух простых, соединенных союзом и (2а)"частицы исчезают" и (2б)"появляются разнообразные частицы". Совсем не уверен, что правило о запятой между предложениеми с общим придаточным распространяется и на "вложенные" предложения.

Да и плохо оно смотрится без запятой. Поэтому еще раз выскажусь, что фраза нуждается хотя бы в минимальной переделке.

(-)---

Valeriy, по прос не по русскому языку. Я еще не совсем забыл физику, ваша фраза мне кажется, противоестественной, чтобы не сказать абсурдной. Само противопоставление энергии частицам в подобном контексте вызывает вопросы. И что вообще такое "частицы разных материй"?

Вы уверены, что эта фраза имеет какое-то отношение к физике? Или это художественная речь псевдоученого литературного героя?

Answer (score 1):

(1)Когда соединяются две частицы разных материй, (2) выделяется энергия, а (3) (эти) частицы исчезают и (4)появляются разнообразные (другие) частицы.

Мне кажется, что **структура предложения такова:** СПП с придаточном времени (предложения 1 и 2) противопоставлены предложениям 3 и 4, связанным союзом И.

В том случае **общим элементом следует считать союз А**, запятая однозначно не ставится, предложения 3 и 4 составляют **одну фразу без паузы между ними**.

Comment: *"3 и 4 составляют одну фразу без паузы между ними"* - это что еще за "географические новости"? Давно это наличие или отсутствие паузы стало определяющим для пунктуации СПС? Да и есть там пауза, без неё очень сложно произнести.

Comment: Паузы бывают разные, в том числе произносительные (через 4-5 слов), даже в простом, но распространенном   предложении может быть несколько пауз. Паузы различаются по длительности, выбор запятой, тире, двоеточия  связан с  паузами различной длительности.  Правило отсутствия запятой при наличии общего элемента как раз и объясняется тесной связью двух предложений, когда между ними может делаться произносительная пауза, но не грамматическая, как в обычном сложном предложении при наличии запятой.

Comment: *Паузы бывают разные, в том числе произносительные* - это мне известно. Но Вы за этим менторством, забыли о сути моего замечания. Каким правилом регулируется постановка запятой между составляющими ССП в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия  паузы между ними? Сама по себе запятая обсуждаема, конечно, но с подобной мотивацией я сталкиваюсь впервые.

Comment: Никакого менторства, конечно, нет (извините, если Вам показалось). Дело в том, что наши правила учитывают только грамматический принцип постановки знаков препинания (интонационный принцип редко упоминается).  Поэтому сослаться на правила нет возможности, хотя в современной грамматике интонация занимает уже важное место при описании различных синтаксических конструкций. Роль  интонации в предложениях с одиночным союзом И можно определить, к примеру, ПО АНАЛОГИИ.

Comment: Бор гудит глУхо, сОнно (пауза, перечислительная интонация, запятая). Бор гудит глухо и сОнно (нет паузы, нет перечислительной интонации и  запятой,  обстоятельства имеют общее тоническое ударение, получается ЕДИНАЯ фраза "глухо и сонно". Конечно, постоянно обращаться к интонации нет необходимости, если есть грамматические правила, но здесь случай ОСОБЫЙ (ведь союз А в правилах в качестве общего элемента в правилах не указывается).

Comment: Хорошо, про менторство не буду, хотя и странно слышать, как в ответ на прямой вопрос получаешь порцию отвлеченных соображений. "Интонационный принцип" на запятые между частями сложного предложения не распространяется. Вообще вы его сильно абсолютизируете. Вот посмотрите, что это такое, далеко ходить не надо.   http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29984 Ну как после всего этого можно мотивировать отсутвие запятой между частями СПП наличием паузы?!